# Func<Owned<T>> vs Func<T> dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I know that `Func<T>` is different from `Func<Owned<T>>` and I know how to inject a dependency of each type. However, I often get confused as in when shall I prefer one over the other?

Assume, I have an application following MVP pattern and I want to inject a view `PrintView`. Then, on what grounds shall I decide that I should inject the view as `Func<PrintView>` or `Func<Owned<PrintView>>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Func<T>` will resolve an item from the lifetime scope that will be disposed when the lifetime scope is released. In the case of, say, an MVC controller:

- Controller gets resolved from the request lifetime scope.
- Calling the `Func<T>` will resolve a `T` from the request lifetime scope.
- When the request lifetime scope is disposed, the controller and any `T` instances will be disposed with the request scope.

`Owned<T>` means *you are explicitly taking responsibility for disposal* of the `T` instance. `Func<Owned<T>>` will get an `Owned<T>` from the lifetime scope.

- Controller gets resolved from the request lifetime scope.
- Calling the `Func<Owned<T>>` will resolve an `Owned<T>` from the request lifetime scope.
- When the request lifetime scope is disposed, the controller is disposed but `Owned<T>` instances are *not disposed*. You would need to do that yourself in some sort of cleanup in the controller or elsewhere in your application code.

`Owned<T>` is really only interesting if you want to take control over the time at which things get disposed. If you don't care or want the lifetime scope disposal to take care of it for you, it's not interesting.

Comment: Is there any way/tool in Visual Studio by which I can monitor the lifetime of my components? Thanks!

Comment: No, but if you do some searches there are questions on here about how you can log when various Autofac events are raised. That may help.

Comment: Okay. I think that would suffice for now. Thanks.