# Should I Dispose instances that are not Owned?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm using Autofac in a project, and I'm trying to do it right.
So I've been reading the documentation and found `Owned<T>`. It seems like it's the right relationship type to use when i want to dispose something by myself - e.g. a `DbContext` which is disposable.

So I changed all my injected factories `Func<DbContext>` to `Func<Owned<DbContext>>`.

The only thing is it feels a little dirty the `Lazy<T>` like behaviour and to put the Owned in the using and depending on a non framework type...

Is it wrong to not use `Owned` at all?

Is there an issue in disposing instances that are not owned by my class like this?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Func<DbContext> _dbcFactory;

    private MyClass(Func<DbContext> dbcFactory)
    {
        _dbcFactory = dbcFactory; // nullcheck etc;
    }
    private void TheMethodWhoUpdate(String newName) 
    {
        using(var dbc  = _dbcFactory())
        {
            var ent = dbc.Table.Single(x => x.id == 3);

            end.Name = newName;
            dbc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

What I was able to imagine (because I can't find a clue on the docs) is that this could lead to some performance issue, because maybe autofac will track that created DbContext instance and try to dispose it again, losing some amount of time (probably very small)... But maybe I'm wrong, and I should stick to the [guide](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html#combining-owned-with-func).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Func<Owned<T>> vs Func<T> dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984172/funcownedt-vs-funct-dependency)

Comment: The real question is: why do you want to manage the lifetime yourself?

Comment: Because sometimes it's needed. This is a big old project I'm migrating, so I need to change as less code as possible, and I need to free resources as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `Func<DbContext> dbcFactory` like shown in your code sample?

You shouldn't do that, for two reasons.

1. It is the container's job to dispose of it - so let it do
   its job.
2. Secondly, if you register that `DbContext` as
   `InstancePerLifetimeScope` then multiple objects (involved in the
   same lifetime scope) will get the **same** instance of the
   `DbContext` - which is problematic if one of them disposes it out
   from under the other one.

Answer (score -1):

When having only one instance of dbcontext (or just any other class) is just not an option (there is so many reason that i won't discuss it here) it is perfectly fine to create new ones.

And have a factory injected instead of just one instance is the way to obtain it while sticking to the dependency injection pattern.

About the `Func<Owned<T>>` vs the `Func<T>` i just found out the hard way that *let the scope do it's job* it is just a bad idea.

I used the `Func<Owned<T>>` approach but even if I disposed all the owned scopes I end up with a HUGE memory leak.

The way that really worked for me is to inject a factory that create the `dbContext` (or whatever you need for just a limited amount of time, or need to control the lifecycle).

That factory should be registered as a single instance.

Comment: In terms of using specific Factory classes in Autofac, https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html may be worth a read.

Comment: Using the profiler is exactly what I did, and what was holding the memory was a stack of idisposable in autofac, the code is a simple plain dbcontext( didn't had any other dependency) and is disposable... Went from 1.5GB to a stable 300MB

Comment: But I still see some reason to use Owned<T> or Function<Owned<T>>, for instance if I had some dependencies in the object being created, so I will try to better understand what went wrong...

Comment: a small repro is quite hard, because i won't have time, and part of a quite big project. But if i figure it out i will surely update this, it was registered like this: builder.Register((c, p) => MyDbContext.StaticFactory(p.TypedAs<IUser>()))) later in the code a smaller scope was being created in that context an IUser was registered as single instance and the context was re-registered like this: builder.Register(c => MyDbContext.StaticFactory(c.Resolve<IUser>())))


We have many db one for each user so it take a parameter (it is for a windows application, where an user can log in)

Comment: Oh, it is a Windows app - you didn't mention that. In that case, 99% chance you did lifetime scopes incorrectly. With web apps it is "easier", the lifetime scope will be automatically per web request. But for Windows apps, it is likely you have scoped it to the lifetime of the app. So, Autofac doesn't call `Dispose` until the scope is finished (which it never is) - so it keeps the connection open and doesn't dispose it. This is expected behaviour. https://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/ may be worth a read. The issue is almost certainly how you are using lifetime scopes.

Comment: isn't the objective of using Owned to create a mini scope ? so you just put it in a using... and voilà!
Maybe... what went wrong was that the scope was resolving an owned of the factory... which then resolved the instance from the parent scope... maybe it was a registration issue...

Comment: If you have done scopes incorrectly then it won't just impact `DbContext`. It will impact **every type** that you have registered with the container that implements `IDisposable`. I seriously suggest you read up on lifetime scopes more. Your current solution might 'work' - but you are fighting against how Autofac wants you to do things. You are making your life **way** harder than it needs to be.

Comment: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html
the introduction to this doc page seems to explain that

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. `Owned` can be used for that, but is generally used rarely - generally you want to let the container do its job. The way you are attacking the problem is sub-optimal. **The whole point** of lifetime scopes, done right, is that you don't have to worry about calling `Dispose`. The reason the container **isn't** doing its job is that you didn't setup the lifetime scope correctly. You can "hack" around it, sure, by using `Owned`. And that works for you - which is awesome. But what you _should_ be doing is using `container.BeginLifetimeScope`.

Comment: The first thing I'd suggest to you is to investigate lifetime scopes to the point where you **understand why you had the 'memory' leak**. That is key here. Autofac wasn't being buggy when it kept those `DbContext` objects alive. It was 100% performing to spec. Once you understand that, then you can decide whether your current approach is best, or whether the more standard way of using lifetime scopes would be more appropriate.

Comment: Ok, i do create lifetime scopes, but those they are very long lived ones, i have one for the app, one for the user (it gets disposed only if the an user change happens), one for each project the user create, and all are nested, i didn't want to bloat the code with lifetimescopes and that doc page seemed to offer a quite good solution...

Comment: you actually convinced me that there is something wrong with my code, it must be something we did wrong with the registrations, i can't investigate right away, but i will and i will make it right, i will leave my second answer there because it is another valid approach (just not as good as letting autofac do it's job, but it is logical and usable, you just get the factory and you can dispose what the factory create right away avoiding to have it held in the container, not optimal